# JXA .- How to open a mail based on ID in Outlook

Tags: outlook, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm stumbling on a simple issue but cannot manage to wrap my head around and make it work.
I'm trying using JAX to open a mail in Outlook based on it's ID. I know that with AppleScript it's dead easy:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    open message id msgID
    activate
end tell
```

But I've no clue how to transform it in Javascript:

```
var outlook = Application("Microsoft Outlook");
outlook.includeStandardAdditions = true;
message = ???? <-- Don't know how to select the message with ID mID
message.open()
```

Comment: This is a very tough question❗️   It should be easy, but, unless I'm missing something obvious, it is not.  I've done a bit of testing, and have posted some questions on a couple of JXA boards, so maybe we'll get an answer.  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
msgID = 76 // example
var outlook = Application("Microsoft Outlook");
outlook.messages.byId(msgID).open()
```

Comment: Many, many thanks !!! It's working properly. Out of curiosity, how do you managed to find this? I was unable to find any documentation related to this.

Comment: I started with this AppleScript `tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to current messages` to get the id of the selected message, the result is  **{message id 76 of application "Microsoft Outlook"}**.
So as it already gave me the **ID**, I got the answer of your question from the result of this JavaScript's command `Application("Microsoft Outlook").currentMessages()`.

Comment: Documentation: Search for "ID" in JavaScript for Automation Release Notes. It gives an example of the standard .byId() selector.